# Why is the binomial coefficient button labeled nCr on most calculators?

Tags: calculator

Most of the time I see the binomial coefficent explained using the variables $n$ and $k$:

$${\binom {n}{k}}={\frac {n!}{k!(n-k)!}}$$

I understand that the `C` stands for combinations (versus `P` for permutations) but why is the button labeled `nCr` and not `nCk` on most calculators?

**Edit**: Since this question got downvoted; the reason for asking is that understanding what and why the key is labeled that way helps me in remembering its function.

Comment: It is just notational preference, nothing more.  Some people like to use $k$.  Some people like to use $r$.  There is no inherent difference in meaning.  This is like asking "*most of the time I hear someone name their dog Fido but other times I hear that people named their dog Pero*"  Different places, different common dog names... same thing here, different places different variable names.

Comment: It's completely arbitrary. We won't know unless we dive deep into the minds of the manufacturers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably from the formula
$$C(n,r)=\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$
Which seems to be the most popular. These letters are just there, you can use different letters if you wish and different countries/schools can opt to do so. I googled "combinatorics permutations equations" and I see the nCr approach mostly, not just on calculators. Yet in school we used k too(sometimes n and m).

But, calculator manufacturers I presume are likely to stick to a single standard for ease of use. That's why you also see f, x and n on functions even though they could be any letters.

Comment: This hits it on the head. Variable names don't matter.